# Import csv's and write them with shiny dashboard

Tags: r, import, shiny, shinydashboard

So I'm writing a shiny program that reads 3 .csv files and then has tabs that display different variations/pivots of the data.  The data is updated daily, and I wanted to have a tab on the shiny dashboard where the user could go and upload the new 3 .csv files.

ToyCode below:

```
    csv1=read.csv("csv1.csv")
    csv2=read.csv("csv2.csv")
    csv3=read.csv("csv3.csv")
    csvother=read.csv("somestatic.csv")

    # Create an header
    header = dashboardHeader(#header Stuff)

    # Create an sidebar
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(.....4 sidebar menus....))

    # Create an body
    body <- dashboardBody(

      fluidPage(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(*****other tabs**** then:
         tabItem(tabName="Thing4",

              fileInput("newcsv1", "Choose new CSV1",
                          multiple = FALSE,
                          accept = c(".csv")), 

        )#End tabItems )#end Fluidpage   )#end Dashboard Body 
ui=dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body)
```

Then the server code

```
    server=function(input, output) {
    output$csv1=renderDT({ #pivot stuff, output table{)
    output$csv2=renderDT({ #pivot stuff, output table{)
    output$csv3=renderDT({ #pivot stuff, output table{)
}
```

So from here, how do I set it up so when the user goes to the 4th tab, and selects the file to import, where do I put the function to process the code...i.e. write the csv then set csv1 equal to the new csv1 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you require:

```
server=function(input, output) {
  output$csv1=renderDT({ #pivot stuff, output table})
  output$csv2=renderDT({ #pivot stuff, output table})
  output$csv3=renderDT({ #pivot stuff, output table})

  values <- reactiveValues(
    csv1 = csv1,
    csv2 = csv2,
    csv3 = csv3
  )

  observeEvent(input$newcsv1, {
     values$csv1=read.csv(input$newcsv1$datapath)
  })
}
```

You'll need to use [reactiveValues](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/reactiveValues.html) for csv1, csv2, and csv3 if they are changing instead of saving them globally. Note that you now need to use `values$csv1` within the server file - e.g.

`output$csv1=renderDT({ #pivot stuff, output table})`

will use `values$csv1` instead of `csv1`. Also look at this link for using [fileInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/fileInput.html).

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be that simple!  thanks!

Comment: Sure, reactiveValues() are really useful. Used together with observeEvent(), etc. shiny apps can be really amazing!